# Does the .includes method in JavaScript loop through the array and case O(n)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, methods

Does the .includes method cause O(n^2) when run with another loop such as in this simple example?

```
function myFn(){
    let age = people.map(person => {
            if(person > 21){
              return "YES";
        } else {
          return "NO";
        }
    return age.includes('NO') ? 'NO' : 'YES';
}
```

Comment: In the worst case it has to check every element in the array. So yes, `myFn` has a complexity of `n^2`

Comment: I was trying to do it with out a second loop and was just curious to see if includes cause a loop.

Comment: How else would it test every element in a collection?

Comment: @JeromeCode try `return people.some(age => age < 21) ? 'NO' : 'YES'`

Comment: I didn't know if it would cause O(^n) when run with another loop.

Comment: How else could `includes()` work without looping through the array? If you want a data structure that doesn't require looping, use a `Set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is [specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes) such that it does indeed go through the array element by element. So that's O(n) (linear). But that's after your `map`, which has already gone **all** the way through the array.

JavaScript engine implementations are free (as always) to optimize provided optimizing doesn't change the semantics of the method.

---

As a side note, though, if you want to look through an array for an element matching an arbitrary condition, `map`+`includes` isn't your best choice; [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) are better, because they short-circuit (stop looping) when they find an element that passes (`some`) or fails (`every`) the test. Your code looks to see if every element in `people` is `> 21`, so that would be:

```
function myFn() {
    return people.every(person => person > 21) ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```